# How to get the current time in c++ in a " Safe " way

Tags: c++, time, c++-chrono

I'm not new to C++, but I mostly only use the most basic standard library features like `<iostream>`, `<vector>`, `<map>`, etc.

Right now, I'm working on a simple game and I'm working on a logger class, but I'm stuck on getting the current time.

Don't get me wrong, I've seen a lot of ways to get the time in StackOverflow and Google, but none of them are "safe" according to Visual Studio.  When I use, for example, `asctime()` or `ctime()`, I get this error:

> ['ctime': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using ctime_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details].

But when I try to do it the good way and use safe versions, I find them even more complicated, for example this is the `ctime()` function:

`ctime(const time_t *const_time)`

compared to `ctime_s()`:

`ctime_s(char *const _Buffer, const size_t _SizeinBytes,const time_t *const _Time)`

Again looking on the Internet didn't help me, so here I am, asking you guys about how to get the current time, and by time I mean something like `10:20` or something similar, using "safe" methods.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/now

Comment: There's some controversy over some "warnings" and "deprecation" messages from microsoft, but anything that involves a pointer to memory you have to deal with is worth avoiding.

Comment: @KennyOstrom this doesn't answer my question I don't want a timer I want to get the current time so my logger will be like [current time] [type of log] [message] or something similar

Comment: Is UTC time sufficient or do you need local time?

Comment: @HowardHinnant I prefer local time

Comment: Easiest route is to turn off the warning.  Next easiest route is to use `ctime_s`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/ctime .  C++20 chrono will offer better options but no one is shipping it today.  There's a preview library of C++20 chrono available (https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) but installing it to handle local time will be more work than just using `ctime_s` for your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `asctime()` and `ctime()` functions are "unsafe" because they return a pointer to static buffers that may or may not be thread-safe depending on implementation, and if they are not thread-safe then they could be overwritten by other threads before you have a chance to use them.

The "more secure" `asctime_s()` and `ctime_s()` functions write to pre-allocated buffers that you must provide, eg:

```
time_t now = time(NULL);
//char *str = asctime(localtime(&now));
tm now_tm = {};
char str[26] = {};
localtime_s(&now_tm, &now);
asctime_s(str, 26, &now_tm);
// use str as needed...
```

```
time_t now = time(NULL);
//char *str = ctime(&now);
char str[26] = {};
ctime_s(str, 26, &now);
// use str as needed...
```

Comment: thank you Remy that worked for me but do you have any idea what is this: 1591408047. this is what I get. I know this is the current time but do you know how I'm supposed to read this

Comment: @Void: that's a UNIX time (see https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php) for "06/06/2020 @ 1:47am (UTC)".

Comment: @VoId The encoding of a `time_t` returned by `time()` is **implementation-defined**, however *most* implementations will return the number of seconds that have elapsed since the POSIX epoch: January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC. If you enter `1591408047` into https://www.epochconverter.com/, it shows `Saturday, June 6, 2020 1:47:27 AM GMT` Functions like `localtime()` and `gmttime()` will convert a `time_t` from its native encoding into a more readable `tm` struct.

Answer (score 6):

Modern C++ has the `<chrono>` header for the purposes of time extraction and manipulation and, once you understand it, it's a *lot* better than the legacy C stuff:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>

int main() {
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto legacyStart = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(start);
    std::cout << std::ctime(&legacyStart) << '\n';
}
```

This can be used in a multitude of ways, including (as shown) outputting the string representation of the date. I realise that's not *necessary* for this simple case but you'd be well advised to move to `<chrono>` if you don't want to be known as a C+ coder<sup>(a)</sup>.

That's especially true if you can use C++20, since that iteration includes calendar functionality (for dates) and time-of-day functionality (for splitting a duration since midnight into individual components like hours, minutes, and seconds).

If you can start using those, you'll never need the legacy C stuff again :-)

---

Regarding whether this is unsafe or not, I think Microsoft often does a disservice to coders in making this decision. I actually turn off these warnings since I *know* the risks involved, and know how to avoid issues.

In any case, I believe I read at some point the `s` was for secure rather than safe, since certain of the replacement functions are *not* safe if you, for example, pass the wrong lengths to them:

```
char dest[10];
strcpy_s(dest, 100, "13 characters");
```

Now no doubt some would say that's the coder's fault because they should know what they're doing, but the same argument could be made for the supposedly *unsafe* functions.

The specific problem with `ctime()` is that it is allowed to return the address of an internal buffer which may be overwritten the next time it's called (and this *may* also include another thread calling it before you're finished with it).

If you know your usage patterns (including any third-party stuff you use), you can easily use `ctime()` without issues.

However, it's not *that* hard, in this case, to use the safer variant, with something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>

int main() {
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto legacyStart = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(start);
    char tmBuff[30];
    ctime_s(tmBuff, sizeof(tmBuff), &legacyStart);
    std::cout << tmBuff << '\n';
}
```

Although you *may* want to consider using `strftime` so you get better control of the output format (such as '"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"`), and therefore a guarantee that the resultant string will fit in the buffer).

---

<sup>(a)</sup> That strange breed that never *quite* made the transition fully from C to C++ :-)

Comment: but how can I get to display that time I can't call std::cout on this. anyway I can convert it to fit inside cout ?

Comment: @VoId `std::ctime()` returns a `char*`, simply assign that to a `std::string` and use that as needed. If you don't like that, you could always use [`std::strftime()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/strftime) instead, or [`std::put_time()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time) with a [`std::ostringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream).

Comment: @Remy, converting it to a string may not help if a thread switch occurs between the storing into the internal buffer and the construction of the string - the internal buffer could still be corrupted, however unlikely. You were right about the code, I pulled it from two separate sources and hopefully it's fixed now.

Comment: @paxdiablo yes, that race condition is why `ctime()` is "unsafe" and `ctime_s()` is preferred.

Comment: Just an FYI to all, the first snippet prints the date in this format: "Fri Sep 30 00:22:56 2022"